# Export PNGs from Adobe Illustrator

Tags: export, png, adobe-illustrator

I'm a beginner trying to design a simple square logo in illustrator (to use as a favicon and as an icon for a chrome extension).  I'd like to export the image as a png in 3 sizes- 16 px, 48 px, and 128 px. The 128 px image looks good upon export but the 48 and 16 px pngs have an unwanted border on the right side (see screenshots, I've zoomed in to make the border easier to see).

Any tips for eliminating this border for the two smaller pngs? Thanks!

[image: screenshot-48-px]

Comment: Did you design it at 128 px and then resize it using a simple fraction, like 1/3 for 48 px?  That would give you a border at 48 px because the icon would come out 43 px.  The border would be preserved if you repeat the process on the 48 px version to get 16 px.

Comment: I rolled the edit back for two reasons.  1) Embedding the image on the page masks the problem (white border on white background).  2) It changed the problem definition.  The OP wants icons that are 16 and 48 px rather than trimmed icons.

Comment: I remade the icon at 16 px and it came out well!